# Can't connect to SQL Database (Java, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, jdbc

I have imported the JDBC library, set it to be compiled, and gave the App permission to access Internet.
When a button on Screen is pressed, it should connect to the database and give me the values to implement in the list.

When I press the button, I can see it giving me the "Connecting to database" text, but after about half a second it says "Exception" as defined in that last catch block.

I commented out the three lines of code in onPostExecute, because when I kept them the App would just crash.

```
public void retrieveData(View view) {
    GetData retrieveData = new GetData();
    retrieveData.execute();


}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String msg = "";

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + DbStrings.DATABASE_URL + "/" + DbStrings.DATABASE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.setText("Connecting to database");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DbStrings.USERNAME, DbStrings.PASSWORD);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM video"; //
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("title");

                buildNames += name + " ### ";

            }

            msg = "Process complete.";

            rs.close();
            conn.close();
            stmt.close();


        } catch(SQLException connError) {
            msg = "An exception was thrown for JDBC.";
            connError.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            msg = "A Class not found exception was thrown.";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            msg = "Exception";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try{
                if(stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                if(conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

        progress.setText(this.msg);

        //names = buildNames.substring(0,buildNames.length()-5).split(" ### ");
        //itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(thisContext, buildNames.substring(0,buildNames.length()-5).split(" ### ")); //crashes
        //namesList.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/115145. Also, please understand that JDBC is not designed for use from mobile devices, which is one of the reasons why Android does not support JDBC.

Comment: This is what I found:
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index '192' received from server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property.
I saw this working in a tutorial, so it shouldn't prevent it from working

Comment: You really should not be connecting directly to a database from an Android app.

Comment: Why not? Is it unsafe? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the stack trace I found this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index '192' received from server.
```

And so I knew what to search for;
I was using an outdated version of JDBC, (3.x). After importing Version 5.1.46, it is now working :).